# My file generate pdf shows only 10% of the screen

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf from my web page with react, I have the react-pdf library but it does not show me the full screen of the pdf document, only 10% of the screen is showing me the pdf.

I import librery

```
import ReactPDF, { Document, Page, Text, Image, StyleSheet, Font, View, PDFViewer } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
```

Define my style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
});
```

My document for generate the file

```
const MyDocument = ({ data }) => (

  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} wrap={false}>

      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header} fixed>
          REPORTE
      </Text>

        <Header
          title={format_config.title}
          subtitle={format_config.subtitle}
          logo={data.empresa.logo}
        />

        <View style={styles.table_title}>
          <Text style={styles.subtitle} >
            {format_config.title_tab}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Ln />


        <View style={styles.table}>
          <View style={styles.tableRow}>
            <View style={styles.tableColHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCellHeader}>COD</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.tableColHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCellHeader}>DESCRIPTION</Text>
            </View>
          </View>


          {
            data.accounts.map((r, i) => {
              return (
                <View style={styles.tableRow} key={i} >
                  <View style={styles.tableColHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.tableCellHeader}>{r['codigo']} </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.tableColHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{r['descripcion']} </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )
            })
          }


        </View>


        <Ln />
        <SectionSigns />
        <View style={styles.table_title}>
          <Text style={styles.subtitle} >
            {format_config.text_footer}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <User user={data.user.nombres} />
        <Footer />
        <Date date={data.date} />
      </View>


    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

I render all the code for generate my file with this code.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PDFViewer>
          <MyDocument data={this.state} />
        </PDFViewer>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But in the display of browser the file this show alone 10% of the doc. I have React JS and react-pdf.

Comment: You can use `height` and `width` props on the `PDFViewer` component to make the viewer larger if the issue is just that the viewer box is too small to show the entire page/document.